# CakePHP3 iterating model not working

Tags: php, orm, cakephp-3.0

I just installed cakephp 3 for the first time. Thinking it was a good idea to move to the newest version of the framework for me new project. Now I'm banging my head against the wall over the new ORM. I've read the docs extensively and have a grip *I think* on how it is supposed to work. For the life of me I can not get results from the database that I can iterate over. I can take the returned results and manually access an index and find the data but if I try to iterate I constantly just get an error about the variable not being defined.

Controller:

```
$this->loadModel('Users');
$this->set('users', $this->paginate($this->Users));
$this->set('_serialize', ['users']);
```

View:

```
<? foreach($users as $user) { ?>
    <?= $user->name ?>
<? } ?>
```

I baked the model, views, and controller. I'm trying to now start to pull data from the database and iterate it. I've tried countless variations of using collections and toArray() on the results and nothing that the docs seem to describe should be working actually work.

What is the most reliable and correct way to get a bunch of results and get them into a point where you can iterate through them in the controller or the view?

Error displayed in view:

```
Notice (8): Undefined variable: user [APP/Template/Pages/display.ctp, line 23]
```

Full Log entry:

```
2015-12-15 22:48:57 Notice: Notice (8): Undefined variable: user in [/Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Default/chronoticker/chronoticker/src/Template/Pages/display.ctp, line 23]
Trace:
Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler::handleError() - CORE/src/Error/BaseErrorHandler.php, line 140
include - APP/Template/Pages/display.ctp, line 23
Cake\View\View::_evaluate() - CORE/src/View/View.php, line 971
Cake\View\View::_render() - CORE/src/View/View.php, line 931
Cake\View\View::render() - CORE/src/View/View.php, line 579
Cake\Controller\Controller::render() - CORE/src/Controller/Controller.php, line 611
Cake\Routing\Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE/src/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 120
Cake\Routing\Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/src/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 87
[main] - ROOT/webroot/index.php, line 37
```

Doing some additional testing I've found this in my view to be the case. It seems like the view refuses to do anything that iterates.

```
<pre>
<?= print_r($user_list[3]) ?> //Will work and return an array of data
</pre>

<? foreach($user_list as $aUser) { ?>
    <?= $aUser['name'] ?> //Does not work. Kicks error about undefined variable
<? } ?>


<? for($x = 0; $x < count($user_list); $x++) { ?>
    <?= $user_list[$x]['name'] ?> //Does not work. gives undefined variable error for $x
<? } ?>
```

Comment: Whenever receiving errors, please post the _complete_, _exact_ error message, and attach the corresponding stacktrace (ideally from the logs, where it is formatted properly). Also the CakePHP error pages/notices output context information that can helpful (like involved variables, arguments, etc).

Comment: I've edited and added the extra information.

Answer (score 2):

Given that it's the `$user` variable that is not being defined, I'd suspect that the loop is not being executed, most probably because your PHP installation has [**short open tags**](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) disabled.

Look at the generated page source code, and you'll probably find the PHP code. Simple fix, do not use short open tags, use `<?php` instead.

Comment: This was definitely it. After enabling short tags in php.ini it still won't let me use short tags. I've changed the code to not use the short tags and it works fine. Man, what a waste of time chasing that down.